# Delphi XE6 - How to implement an Android interface and create a listener?

Tags: android, delphi, interface, nullpointerexception, delphi-xe6

I tried to implement a thing similar to the one done in `FMX.Advertising.Android`.

```
type
  // Forward declaration
  JAttentiveListener = interface;   //com.pack.AttentiveListener
  //...
  JAttentiveListenerClass = interface(IJavaClass)
  ['{28A2CA13-A965-4EAB-A4F0-481E20C9AF2A}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/pack/AttentiveListener')]
  JAttentiveListener = interface(IJavaInstance)
  ['{45D40262-E5C2-4650-B64A-4C5D56EA6107}']
    {Methods}
    procedure onClicked; cdecl;
    procedure onNotReceived(message1: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onReceived; cdecl;
  end;
  TJAttentiveListener = class(TJavaGenericImport<JAttentiveListenerClass, JAttentiveListener>) end;

  TMyListener = class(TJavaLocal, JAttentiveListener)     // JAttentiveListener is Android interface imported above using JNI
  private
    FObj: TCallbackObj;
  public
    constructor Create(Obj: TCallbackObj);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure onClicked; cdecl;
    procedure onNotReceived(message1: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onReceived; cdecl;
  end;

{TMyListener}

constructor TMyListener.Create(Obj: TCallbackObj);
begin
  inherited Create;   // exception here.
  FObj := Obj;
end;
```

Constructor is called in UI thread and throws `NullPointerException` during the call to a parent's constructor. There are following messages in a log:
[image: [dvmFindClassByName rejecting, java.lang.NullPointerException]

I've tried to debug step-by-step, and stepped into `TJavaLocal`'s c-tor. Exception occurs in the following statement of this c-tor:

```
FLocalRefObjectID := AJNIEnv^.CallObjectMethodA(AJNIEnv, AJNIObject, CreateProxyClass, PJNIValue(ArgsToJNIValues([ClsID, Self])));
HandleJNIException(AJNIEnv);    // NullPointerException is here
```

---

Why does the same thing work in `FMX.Advertising.Android` and doesn't work in my code? (I'm trying to create a listener implementing an interface and doing everything like in `AdsListener` from `FMX.Advertising.Android`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay more attention to the log output. `NullPointerException` is preceded by 'dvmFindClassByName rejecting X', and it means that **dalvik can't find the class of listener**. Maybe it is absent in a classes.dex file, maybe you've specified the wrong signature in `[JavaSignature('com/pack/AttentiveListener')]`.